# efficient wait until NAS boots to mount it

Tags: shell

Problem: Server boots 3 minutes, Raspberry Pi boots 30 seconds. After a power outage, RPi boots faster and does not mount the NAS disk.

This particular RPi needs disk to be able to record to it. Hence without the (external) disk mounted, RPi is useless. I was using RPi autostart.sh to:

```
mount -t nfs 192.168.1.5:/Public/Video/TV /storage/nas -o nolock;
```

when I realised this problem. So, I created a loop in RPi's autostart.sh where I mount NAS. During normal operation (once the mount is achieved) this problem can not occur any more: should only one of them reboot, RPi mount will work OK (I think).

Would this be a good solution (executed only at RPi startup) and could it be done better or more elegantly?

```
until mountpoint -q /storage/nas || mount -t nfs 192.168.1.5:/Public/Video/TV /storage/nas -o nolock; do sleep 30; done
```

This should not try to mount if allready mounted, and otherwise - mount. Plus, wait for a retry until mounted. Seems to work as intended, except that RPi will boot (not WAIT for mount) but this RPi (actually Kodi) will be frozen until NAS is mounted.

Only thing I can see colud be added here is: send WOL to NAS prior to sleep.

Clarification: This is OPENelec RPi instllation, and there is fstab not used, but the method desribed above.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding the **bg** mount option for nfs, if you have it. [man 5 nfs](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs):

> If the bg option is  specified,  a  timeout  or  failure
>     causes  the  mount(8) command to fork a child which continues to attempt to mount the export.  The parent immediately returns with a zero exit code.  This is known as
>     a "background" mount.

Comment: No man on RPi, but seems like better solution than mine. Mine works, but I would prefer it done elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really using a shell script and not fstab to mount your drives at boot ?

Read up on /etc/fstab (run the command *man fstab*) and in particular, look at the _netdev option, so you end up with something like.

```
10.10.10.10:/srv/share /mnt/mymnt   nfs4    defaults,noexec,nosuid,_netdev,auto     0       0
```

Disclaimer: Do not copy paste the above without first reading up on fstab !

P.S. Depending on your OS, nobootwait may also be worth exploring as an option.

P.S.P.S. See also mount options in nfs(5)

Comment: This is supposed to be a correct (old fashioned) way for Raspberry. But, I will check your suggestion. Hmm,  # man fstab
prints out: -sh: man: not found

Comment: Interesting... just checked on a "toy" Pi I've got here, /etc/fstab exists and man fstab returns the expected output ?

Comment: According to `mount(8)` `_netdev` just prevents the system from booting until networking has been enabled. If the NFS server takes longer to boot than the client, there's a good chance the client will enable networking before the NFS server is up.

Comment: @Henrik, my man page says of _netdev  "used  to  prevent  the  system  from  attempting to mount these filesystems until the network has been enabled on the system"

Comment: @LittleCode Mine says the same, but my point is that it might not be enough, because "network has been enabled on the system" is in no way correlated to "NFS server being up".

Comment: @Henrik nfs(5) mount options ....  If the bg option is specified, a  timeout  or  failure  causes  the mount(8)  command  to  fork  a  child which continues to attempt to mount the export.  The parent immediately returns with a zero  exit code.  This is known as a "background" mount.  Maybe that in combination with some of the timeout options ?

Comment: @LittleCode I think so, but that is essentially meuh's answer.

Comment: @Little Code ...just checked on a "toy" Pi I ...- I neglected to mention this was regarding OPENelec installation. Currently I am testing OSMC and there seems to exist standard etc/fstab